# Running already deployed vue 3 project on virtual machine server in Debian - getting error

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, vuejs3

Hello this is my first time trying to run a vue on linux. In a normal hosting I just need to copy and paste in public the dist folder. I was reading tutorials saying I need to install nginx and node, I did that and when trying to access to the assigned link, I can see the front part of the app but just pieces, and is not functional at all, and in the browser console I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: 9
    at S (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:32)
    at f (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:167)
    at Z (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:725)
    at ee (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:739)
    at Object.te [as nextToken] (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:781)
    at h (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:916)
    at d (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:1015)
    at v (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:1054)
    at Object.g [as parse] (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:1069)
    at ne (message-compiler.esm-bundler.js:1322)
Ze @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:225
```

I only have the dist folder, I was wondering if I need the whole project there as well. Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Please share more details. A syntax error in JS code does not relate to Debian, or VMs after all

Comment: At the beginning I tried this tutorial: https://thucnc.medium.com/deploy-a-vuejs-web-app-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-f93860219030.

Don't think is the project, because I can run it using the "Web server for Chrome" plugin